# Hibernate annotation many-to-one issue

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have some issue with save object with one to many relationship. In my problem One UserGrop has many UserPermissions. Forthat relation ship I have create my domain class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_usergroup")
public class UserGroup implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)    
    @Column(name="userGroupId")
    private long userGroupId;

    @Column(name = "userGroupName")
    private String userGroupName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="userGroup",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserPermissions> userPermissions = new HashSet<UserPermissions>(0);



}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_group_permissions")
public class UserPermissions implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long userPermissionId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade =CascadeType.ALL)     
    @JoinColumn(name="userGroupId",nullable=false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "userGroupId")
    private UserGroup userGroup;


}
```

But When saving UserGroup, it save hat UserPermisions Objects also. There with the table it does not have any relationship(**when retrieving UserGroup object, it doesn't return Set of UserPermisions objects**).

DB:

```
+------------------+-------------+
--+
| userPermissionId | userGroupId |
e |
+------------------+-------------+
--+
|               33 |        NULL |
  |
|               34 |        NULL |
  |
|               35 |        NULL |
  |
|               36 |        NULL |
  |
|               37 |        NULL |
  |
|               38 |        NULL |
  |
|               39 |        NULL |
  |
|               40 |        NULL |
  |
+------------------+-------------+
--+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can any body help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `@OneToMany` on `UserGroup.userPermissions` you have `mappedBy="userGroup"`. This means the `userGroup` property in `UserPermisions` is responsible for the relation. I guess you don't set that property and upon saving it's still null.

Comment: I am only saving UserGroup Object only, I have set 8 UserPermisions  object there and just save the UserGroup object. I didn't save UserPermisions  object separately.

Comment: @Chandana Yes but the `Cascade.ALL` means that save events are cascaded, thus UserPermissions are saved, too. Nevertheless, you need to save the UserPermissions since those are responsible for the relation (and don't forget to fill the `userGroup` field).

Comment: I have some question regarding this?
Why need to set UserGroup Object in to UserPermisions  object?